# Why does my click event listener stop working after I re-render my gameboard?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Tic Tac Toe game and cannot figure out what exactly is causing this issue. My gameboard renders on the initial page load as a blank board. I can click on any space and if I run `console.log(gameboardObject.gameboardArray);` in my browser's console, it shows that the array item that correlates to the space that was clicked successfully updated to an 'X'. This does not update visually on the board though. When I run `gameboardObject.renderGameboard();`(in the browser's console) or I update the `markSpace();` function to include `renderGameboard();` it does update the board but it seems that after, it will no accept any new inputs/clicks. I've tried removing the eventlistener and readding it but that didn't work and I cannot figure out what is causing this issue. What am I missing?

```
const gameboardObject =  (function () {
    let gameboardArray = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];

    function renderGameboard() {
        let gameboard = document.getElementById('gameboard');
        
        gameboard.innerHTML = '';
        
        let gameboardSpaces = [];

        // create a loop that will iterate over each item in the gameboardArray
        for (let i = 0; i < gameboardArray.length; i++) {
            let gameboard = document.getElementById('gameboard');
            let space = document.createElement('div');

            space.setAttribute('id', `boardspace-${i}`);
            space.setAttribute('class', 'boardSpaces');
            space.textContent = gameboardArray[i];
            
            gameboard.appendChild(space);
            gameboardSpaces.push(space);
        };

        return gameboardSpaces;
    };

    // renders gameboard & assigns it to a variable for future use
    let gameboardSpaces = renderGameboard();
    
    function selectSpace() {
        for (let i = 0; i < gameboardSpaces.length; i++) {
            let space = gameboardSpaces[i];

            space.addEventListener('click', () => {
                markSpace(space, i);
            });
        };

    };

    selectSpace();
    
    function markSpace(space, index) {
        gameboardArray[index] = 'X';
        // this is where i would include the renderGameboard() function
        selectSpace();
    };

    return { 
        gameboardArray,
        renderGameboard,
        markSpace,
        selectSpace,
    };
    
})();
```

Comment: You clear the `gameboard`, create new elements, attach listeners to those elements, and then remove the elements and create new ones, but don't attach new listeners. You can attach a single listener to the `gameboard` instead, and since events bubble up, a click on an element contained inside the `gameboard` can be handled by the single event handler. You get the element that was clicked in the 'target' attribute of the event object. Consider using `button` instead of `div` and your game will automatically be  playable by keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

When you run the program initially, you call `let gameboardSpaces = renderGameboard();` which *deletes everything and then creates some HTML elements* and then you call `selectSpace();` which **adds event listeners** to those elements.

Later when you call `gameboardObject.renderGameboard();` you create creating new elements but you aren't calling `selectSpace()` so no event listeners get added to them.

Comment: So it's more of an issue of the new elements not having event listeners as opposed to the gameboardSpaces render deleting everything?